# cabal custom build include dir

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have a cabal file with a custom build to (calls `Setup.hs` to perform some preprocessing).  But `Setup.hs` imports `Project.Preprocessor`, which is under `src` as show below.

```
project.cabal
Setup.hs
src/Project/Preprocessor.hs
src/Project/OtherFiles...
```

This fails since `src` is not included (as in `runghc -isrc Setup.hs build`).

```
dist\setup\setup.hs:3:18:
  Could not find module Project.Preprocessor
  ...
```

*Is there any way to include an extra source directory for build process?*

I.e. like `runghci -isrc Setup.hs` (but from `cabal build`).

EDIT: I did verify that `runghc -isrc Setup.hs build` executes. :-)

Thanks!

Comment: If Project.Preprocessor is part of the library, I don't think cabal can use it to build the library itself. You may have to hack this together yourself (or perhaps there is some other tool). If it isn't in the library, it is not inconceivable that it should just be in the root directory (or the code inside Setup.hs). In general, I believe that `hs-source-dirs: src` indicates to look in 'src' for source files. By default, it only looks in the project root.

Comment: Yeah, `hs-source-dirs` doesn't seem to include stuff for `Setup.hs`, which makes sense. I can re-root it, I just wondered if `cabal` had a knob to address this.